# Performance of API when controller calls one service vs two services

Tags: node.js, mongodb, dependency-injection, aggregation-framework, nestjs

We are developing an e-commerce backend on the NestJS + MongoDB framework. One of our APIs has the following route:
<https://{{baseurl}}/store/{{lang}}/getproducts?{{field1=value1}}&... ...> It receives filter criteria and returns 2 arrays: array of filters and its values & array of products to show.

Frontend then renders these two arrays in catalog block, where there are two sections:

1. Filter list
2. Product list

To develop the backend we created product.controller and product.service classes. Produt.service.ts is injectable and is injected in product.controller.ts constructor. In product.service.ts we have 2 methods that return:

1. Filter list
2. Product list

For each query in MongoDB, we use aggregation pipelines. The code inside the method runs in the chain of multiple conditions and at the end constructs one aggregation statement and sends the request to DB.

We are using Mongoose library for DB requests.

The problem is the performance of the API as there are 150k+ products in the database. As one of the possible performance improvements, we created two injectable services for each entity, but it did not give any improvement.

Any idea would be helpful!

Comment: When is about performance there are two primary factors. 
first: guarantee your indexes are right set up for your searches.
second: the way you created your aggregation is really important, so filter everything before sort, merge, etc...

Comment: Share with us your code in your controller, service and, query.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/justgodu/438370cd6fbf0e759975df745b01c381 Thanks!

Comment: How are the database indexes for this collection?

Comment: @LCK I'd recommend reading https://www.mongodb.com/developer/article/mongodb-schema-design-best-practices/ **reducing the amount of loops you have** *and* use mongodb correctly, you can eliminate *most* of your `Service` by pushing logic to your database using querying/indexes/aggregation (like you have in places). Reduce the amount of service calls you make too. If you want a full answer - share your schema too please